# Will programming using JDK 7 allow the application to run on JRE 6?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am programming in Eclipse. I never change anything about the default compile setting of Eclipse, or anything else.

If I have JDK 7 installed on my computer. Should my compiled Runnable JAR have any problem running on an older JRE, assuming that the older JRE supports all my programs features?

For example, if I program an application in Eclipse, with the latest JDK installed - should the program have a problem running on a slightly older JRE?

If the answer to this is "yes" - How can I change this? How can I allow my program to run on older JREs than my JDK? Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: You can tell Eclipse about multiple JDKs you have installed and choose which one to use for each project.

Comment: @greg-449 Is this the 'standard' way to allow my application to run on older versions of Java? If I don't do this, is the 'default' for my application to be able to run only on the JRE suitable for the JDK I programmed with?

Comment: It is hard to be sure you have not used something from the runtime libraries that is Java 7 specific, much safer to compile again the Java 6 libraries.

Comment: @greg-449 There's actually a Maven plugin ("animal sniffer") which will check that :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code will only run on JRE 6 of you compile it for JRE 6. Check your compiler settings (Project->Properties->Java Compiler) and make sure that you compile for Java 6, otherwise users will get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` if they don't have Java 7 installed.

You also have to make sure to either not use any Java 7 features (e.g. `java.nio.Path`), or install the Java 6 JDK and use it to compile your application, otherwise you'll get missing method/class exceptions when running the application on Java 6 (you'll instead get compile time errors when using JDK 6).

Comment: I see. So let me ask you a question: If I very rarely use features that were introduced in Java 7, would it be a smart idea to simply uninstall JDK 7, install JDK 6 instead, and develop this way? This would ensure that more people will be able to run my program, right?

Comment: This way both Java 6 and Java 7 computers will be able to run my applications, right?

Comment: @user3150201 You can install JDK 6 alongside JDK 7, just make sure to configure Eclipse to use JDK 6 for projects that you want to run with JRE 6.

Answer (score 2):

The Java runtime that Eclipse uses does not have to be the same that your project uses. You can set the runtime of your project in the project's properties:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-ProjectConfiguration.htm

Java 7 is backwards compatible, meaning older Java programs will run in this version of Java. However, Java versions are never forwards compatible. Meaning a program written in Java 7 will not necessarily compile in Java 6 and a program written in Java 6 will not necessarily compile in Java 5. That is because Java 7 contains features that Java 6 does not contain, like strings in switch statements, and Java 6 contains features Java 5 does not contain, like scripting language support (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history for an overview).

Also lack of forwards compatibility means Java programs compiled in a newer version of Java will not run on an older version of the Java runtime. The java compiler specifically protects compiled java class files with a version identifier to not run these classes when they are compiled in newer version of Java.

If you are careful to avoid Java 7 features you can write a Java program in Java 7 that will compile and run in Java 6. If you know however that your program needs to run in Java 6 it is best to set your project's runtime to Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am aware that different Java versions have different features. But what I'd like to know, is this: Let's say I made a program using JDK 7, but this program doesn't use any feature that JRE 6 doesn't support. My question is if I need to compile my program in some special way, or do anything special, so it will be able to run on JRE 6 - or is compiling as usual enough?

Comment: Extended my answer. The compiler is not forwards compatible.

Comment: I see. So basically, if I'm programming in Eclipse with JDK 7 installed on my computer, I need to *specifically* tell Eclipse to compile the program to run also on JRE 6. (Even if my program doesn't use any feature that JRE 6 doesn't support). Is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Of course you will have to install JRE/JDK 6 as well on your machine.

Comment: I went to Oracle's site to download JDK 6. It says there: *They (older released) are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.*
How come it's saying this, if the only way to develop for computers with older JREs, is by doing this?

Comment: If you develop for Java 6, people who have Java 6 *and newer* installed can run your program. It is recommend however that people / production environments install the latest Java runtime so they can benefit from security patches.

Comment: I see. I tried to change the JRE for my project, not sure it worked. Would you say if what I did is correct?
1- I download JRE 1.6 from Oracle's site.
2- I set the compiler compliance level for my project, to 1.6.
3- I installed the 1.6 JRE from Eclipse's 'installed JREs' screen.
4- In the "Java build path" window of my project, I pressed 'libraries'. I pressed 'JRE system library', pressed 'edit', and set "alternate JRE" to jre6.
Is all of this the correct way to do this?